# Is there an API that can take a div from a webpage and turn it into an image?

Tags: api, image, web-services

Is there an API that can take the content from a div from a webpage and convert it into an image?

Comment: I researched this and found several APIs. The ones with decent features and liberal rate limits were all paid services. I ended up building my own with VNC. If you just want to render some HTML like a browser would and create a virtual screenshot, you can do that with webkit, from what I understand, but I don't know enough about it to post an answer. Or, maybe I'm totally misunderstanding the question. More details would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [thumbalizr](http://www.thumbalizr.com/). It also has an API.

Here's a `1280px` [screenshot](http://beta.thumbalizr.com/app/thumbs/?src=/thumbs/onl/source/e5/e57070205cc920c454c6e87a471ffa20.png&w=1280&q=0&enc=) of this page.

To get just the div that you are interested in, find the div's [offsets](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [dimensions](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/), then use any [image manipulation library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158756/what-is-the-best-image-manipulation-library) to carve out those coordinates from the entire image starting at `(offsetX, offsetY)` and having dimensions `(width, height)`.

Answer (score 1):

If the site which includes the div is in your control. Add a border in a unique color to the div.
Then use extrenal service like thumbalizr to get the image and clip it in according to the unique color frame.

This setup can run via server side php/gd imagemagick. or similar (javascript/ . Net)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you could do this with jquery:

```
$("div").replaceWith('<img />');
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really phrase my question well, I've edited it now to be more clear.